# Return int array with values greater than threshold

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach, integer

I need to add values to an int[] that are greater than a specific threshold. It does not work for me, because it returns wrong values. For example: "Output for values above 78: [85, 93, 81, 79, 81, 93]", but I get [93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93]. Why is that so? Thank you.

```
public int[] getValuesAboveThreshold(int threshold) {

        // Output for values above 78: [85, 93, 81, 79, 81, 93]

        int[] a = new int[] { 58, 78, 61, 72, 93, 81, 79, 78, 75, 81, 93 };

        int temp[] = new int[1];

        for (int d : a) {

            if (d > threshold) {

                System.out.println(d);

                temp = new int[temp.length + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

                    temp[i] = d;

                }

            }

        }

        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: Please explain the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Well look at that, we just had a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393907)

Comment: Your logic has one critical issue: You replace your old `int[] temp` with a new array (presumably to add the new value), but then overwrite _every_ entry with the same `d` value. You likely wanted to call `System#arrayCopy` (or to use that loop) to move over the old data into a new array first, before assigning to `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return ArrayList instead of int[]. Try this code example

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getValuesAboveThreshold(int threshold) {

    // Output for values above 78: [85, 93, 81, 79, 81, 93]

    int[] a = new int[] { 58, 78, 61, 72, 93, 81, 79, 78, 75, 81, 93 };

    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int d : a) {

        if (d > threshold) {

            temp.add(d);

        }

    }

    return temp;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialise the temp array, it defaults to the default value of int and when you loop it to add values, it adds 'd' to all indexes. Try ArrayList instead:

```
           int[] a = new int[] { 58, 78, 61, 72, 93, 81, 79, 78, 75, 81, 93 };
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int d : a) {
                if (d > 73) {
                    System.out.println(d);             
                        temp.add(d);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Array is a container of data, that occupies a contiguous block of memory, which is being allocated accordingly to the specified array's size when a new instance of an array is being created.

Arrays can't grow or shrink, you always need to provide array's length while creating a new array (*unless you're specifying the contents of the array in curly braces* `{A,B,C}`, *which implicitly gives information about required capacity*).

In order to generate an array as a result, firstly you need to find out the number of elements that exceed the threshold, and then create an array which would store the result:

```
public int[] getValuesAboveThreshold(int[] a, int threshold) {
    
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i : a) if (i > threshold) count++;
    
    int[] res = new int[count];
    int pos = 0; // position in the resulting array
    
    for (int i : a) if (i > threshold) res[pos++] = i; // assign the element and move the position forward
    
    return res;
}
```

The same logic can be implemented using Stream API in a single statement:

```
public int[] getValuesAboveThreshold(int[] a, int threshold) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(a)
        .filter(i -> i > threshold)
        .toArray();
}
```